# Why is a super class method called when the signature specifies an interface?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Why the superclass `run` method is called without error in the following code?

```
public interface ISchedulingTask {
    public void run();
}

public class SerialTask {
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("SerialTask");
    }
}

public class SchedulingTask extends SerialTask implements ISchedulingTask {}

public class SchedulingTaskPane {
    public SchedulingTaskPane(ISchedulingTask task){
        task.run();
    }
}

@Test
public void test(){
    SchedulingTask task = new SchedulingTask();
    SchedulingTaskPane paneProduction = new SchedulingTaskPane(task);
}
```

The code outputs `SerialTask` without any problems, but I don't understand this behavior. Why is a super class method called, even though the constructor specifies `ISchedulingTask`?

Comment: Because in your test you declared `task` as a `SchedulingTask`, which is a `ISchedulingTask`, but the important thing is its concrete type (what it really is at runtime), i.e. a `SchedulingTask`.

Answer (score 0):

SchedulingTask is the child of SerialTask, and both the class now inherits from the interface, makes them type of ISchedulingTask. The only implementation of run() method is in the  SerialTask. Now you are passing instance of SchedulingTask while creating instance of in the SchedulingTaskPane, on which you are invoking run method. Now SchedulingTask does not override the implementation of its parent class, so it would have to rely on super class. I hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected. Take a look at the [Java Tutorial for Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Interfaces in Java only describe a certain "contract", i.e., every class implementing an interface has to offer all the methods in the interface.

`SchedulingTask` extends `SerialTask`, so the method `SerialTask.run` is now part of `SchedulingTask`. `SchedulingTask` implements the interface `ISchedulingTask` - this means "I sign a contract that I have all the methods in ISchedulingTask". This "contract" is fulfilled, because `SchedulingTask` **inherits** the method from `SerialTask`.

Remember, inheritance ("extends") represents a "is a"-relationship, i.e., a SchedulingTask **is a** SerialTask.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `SchedulingTask` it is a class that extends the `SerialTask` parent class, and it also declares that it implements the `ISchedulingTask` interface. By implementing an interface all that it means is that `SchedulingTask` promises to implement the interface so anyone using that class can know there is a `run()` method in it.  Note that the interface does not actually implement the `run` function, it simply declares that it exists in that specific signature (takes no parameters and returns nothing).

Since `SerialTask` implements the `run` public function then anything that extends it will also have that implementation. In fact in the code you gave that is the only place that the `run` function is actually implemented.

Note that `SchedulingTask` does **not** implement the `run` function though it says it implements the interface. Normally this would be a compile-time error since the class doesn't implement the required interface functions, but since its parent does have it, all is good and that's the function that gets used at rutime.

A better way to arrange things would be to make the `SerialTask` class implement the `ISchedulingTask` interface since that's where it really is implemented. Since `SchedulingTask` is extending it, it automatically implements the interface also, so nothing really changes in terms of how users of `SchedulingTask` see its functionality but it's more clear about where the `run` function is from.

Note that any subclass that extends the parent or implements the interface is free to implement their own version of the `run` function and that the runtime will use the first one that it comes across.

The `run` function is searched for in this order:

1. SchedulingTask.run -> doesn't explicitly exist in the class
2. parent: SerialTask.run -> does exist so is used

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `SchedulingTask` inherited `SerialTask` class, `SchedulingTask` considers have an implementation to the `run` method. So it's run successfully.

But if you removed the `run` method from `SerialTask` class will cause a compile-time error, you have to implement `run` from `ISchedulingTask`.